# How to list directories size from a tar.gz archive using bash

Tags: bash, tar, archive

I have a huge tgz archive and I know there are several directories there, no files in the root.

I want to know exact size of directories files inside to estimate if they'll fit in my mounted volumes.

I've found this thread helping https://stackoverflow.com/a/11721660/1004388

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner would do the trick:

```
tar tzvf /tmp/root.tgz | sed 's/ \+/ /g' | cut -f3,6- -d' ' | cut -f1 -d'/' | awk '{
    arr[$2]+=$1
   }
   END {
     for (key in arr) printf("%s\t%s\n", key, arr[key])
   }'
```

Example output:

```
usr 821233945
boot    11150620
```

Explanation:

1. `tar tzvf filename` - lists all files in archive in a `ll -r` style
2. `sed` contracts multiple spaces into single to help cutting
3. first `cut` cuts third and sixth fields and leaves everything after the sixth field intact, considering the delimiter is space - now we have size in first column and file path in second column
4. second `cut`: since we need only top-level entries, we cut off with the first directory separator - only first field, considering `/` is the separator
5. `awk` is used to group by second field, summing the first one

Comment: I had to remove the z (mine wasn't gzipped)  and change the second cut to -f1,2 because mine all started with ./

-- Very useful +1

Answer (score 0):

*(Posting as a response, because I cannot comment yet.)*

The response of Ilya above is correct, but on my system (Mac OS), the output of `tar tzvf /tmp/root.tgz` had a different column layout, so I had to replace the first `sed` and `cut` with `awk '{ print $5,$9 }'` (i.e. keep only the 5th and 9th column), giving this new one-liner:

```
tar tzvf /tmp/root.tgz | awk '{ print $5,$9 }' | cut -f1 -d'/' | awk '{
    arr[$2]+=$1
   }
   END {
     for (key in arr) printf("%s\t%s\n", key, arr[key])
   }'
```