# Safely extract zip and tar.gz files with python/unix

Tags: python, security, unix, zip, tar

I'm building an application where users will be able to upload files and I'll need to extract them on my server. I'm concerned about the multiple security vulnerabilities this could suppose.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060069/safely-extract-zip-or-tar-using-python) poses a question similar to mine, but only seems to address relative file extraction.

I haven't found any information relative to zip and tar.gz files with respect to size bombs (also known as gzip). Should I handle that case manually checking the size before extracting? That looks dangerous for someone not aware of such vulnerability.

The final question is: Is there any updated information with respect to safely handling zip and tar.gz files, specially taking into account the two previous sources of vulnerabilities? Do I also wonder if there is any other concern not mentioned in this post that I'm not aware about that could pose a security treat.

This question is asked from the Python perspective, but other information relative to safely handling those files with unix tools are welcome.

I've also found relevant information to extracting tar files [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276959/how-do-i-securely-extract-an-untrusted-tar-file).

Comment: I think [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2712173) with [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11721660/6620967) will help you!

Comment: This is in the line of what I'm looking for, but from a broader point of view. Maybe a Python library with a size limit that uncompresses any kind of files? My real-problem here requires me to generate a list of shell commands to handle the uncompression and post-processing of the files. I cannot create commands on previous of shell execution, I can only append that information from python directly and I'm reticent on on having to use a subproccess. But that is a little bit too much out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

For tar specifically, the documentation lists recommendations to take into account when decompressing untrusted archives:

> Warning Never extract archives from untrusted sources without prior
> inspection. It is possible that files are created outside of path,
> e.g. members that have absolute filenames starting with "/" or
> filenames with two dots "..". Set filter='data' to prevent the most
> dangerous security issues, and read the Extraction filters section for
> details.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall

---

There are filters to use that add security checks for some of the common malicious behavior (such as `data` filter), that will become the default filter starting 3.14 (for now, it needs to be used explicitly). The filter feature itself was not available before python 3.12, but it has been backported to some of the earlier releases.

Apart from that, there are things it is not checking, and you will have to handle those yourself. To do that, you will need to implement a custom filter to detect the remaining scenarios.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#hints-for-further-verification